# High-Speed Website Screenshots with Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, reinforcement-learning

I need to take screenshots of a website continuously and pipe these data into a python array as fast as possible. Desirable would be at least 30 fps. It would be nice to have one screenshot/frame per function call, because I have to inject some JavaScript to the website after each frame.
The website is running a webgl canvas and is expecting keyboard input.

I already tried to make it with selenium and headless Firefox, but this is way too slow. What do you think is the best way to go to get close to my requirements?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to use [Python MSS](https://github.com/BoboTiG/python-mss). This library is intended exactly to take screenshots really fast. It is currently maintainable and cross-platform, and has good documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This might be a solution. But the problem here is, that I need to know the exact position and dimensions of the browser/canvas on the screen. Do you know if it is possible with MSS to determine the position of the browser window? Or if not, do you have an idea how to do this in python?

Comment: Ah okay, I can check that via JavaScript. Thanks, I will try this.